# How many numbers to trim in from the data if the amount of numbers is odd?

Tags: statistics

If I have a data of 30 numbers such as: 14
14
19
18
21
28
24
23
22
25
24
27
28
29
27
25
24
27
30
33
30
28
29
31
38
31
25
24
29
23

and I need to trim 10% that means 3 numbers but the problem is that both ends need identical trimming. So how will I trim the three numbers.

Comment: Why do you need to trim? Who told you it had to be 10 percent? These might help us answer your questions.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please do not be discouraged by the down-votes (one of which I have canceled). This is a simple problem, and I believe you stated your point of confusion very clearly. Nevertheless, it is a good idea to give a little more context (nature of course and assignment, what you have tried so far, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

One use of 'trimming' is to get a 'trimmed mean'.

Begin by sorting the data from smallest to largest. Then trim symmetrically from each
tail: Start by removing the smallest and largest observations,
then the second smallest and largest, and so on.

I believe most software continues trimming until "nearly" the desired percentage percentage is reached, but not more.
[This is the method shown in [this link](http://www.easycalculation.com/statistics/learn-trimmed-mean.php).]

So in your case, you'd need to remove the smallest
and largest ('trimming' two values: 14 and 38), and then stop.
Finally, sum the 28 untrimmed values and divide by 28.

*Note:* If you were doing a 10% trimmed mean of a sample 44 observations,
there would be no way to trim exactly 4.4 observations. You would
trim the top two and the bottom two.